# PyQT crash ( underlying C/C++ object has been deleted ) "after" clear QTreeWidget

Tags: python, qt, list, crash, qtreewidget

i try to build a realtime search for a QTreeWidget, that means that i have a QLineEdit and when im typing, i will filter the shown results in the QTreeWidget.

At the moment i get the "still shown itmes" with QTreeWidget.findItems()

```
foundItems  = mainForm.ui.treeShips.findItems(text,QtCore.Qt.MatchContains)
```

later i clear the QTreeWidget ( mainForm.ui.treeShips) with

```
mainForm.ui.treeShips.clear()
```

then i want to add the "still shown items" with

```
mainForm.ui.treeShips.addTopLevelItems(foundItems)
```

but then the programm crashes with the "underlying C/C++ object has been deleted" error

My first idea is, that with clearing the treeShips, the content of foundItems got cleared too cause the objects of foundItems ( print(foundItems) ) and the objects of treeShips have the same adresses and when the programm want to work with this list, it crash.

Does someone know how to fix it,
or have a better idea to apply such a "search filter" ?

( i hope i could describe my problem correctly :) )

thanks and best regards

Answer (score 1):

i found a workaround based on the 2nd idea from Neox.

I iterate all items in the tree and set the hidden flag on true ( setHidden(True) )
and then i iterate the foundItems and set the hidden flag on false ( i think that works, cause both lists have the same adresses )

```
for item in mainForm.ui.treeShips.findItems("",QtCore.Qt.MatchContains):
    item.setHidden(True)

for item in foundItems:
    item.setHidden(False)
```

But i dont know if that isnt a dirty way, but it works :)

I hope that this will help other ppl who have the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you call `clear` function on a `QTreeWidgetItem` the items are deleted so the error you get is no surprise. You can see it in the following excerpt of the `QTreeWidget` implementation:

```
void QTreeWidget::clear()
{
    Q_D(QTreeWidget);
    selectionModel()->clear();
    //the treeModel here is QTreeModel, refer to snippet below
    d->treeModel()->clear();
}


void QTreeModel::clear()
{
    SkipSorting skipSorting(this);
    for (int i = 0; i < rootItem->childCount(); ++i) {
        QTreeWidgetItem *item = rootItem->children.at(i);
        item->par = 0;
        item->view = 0;
        delete item;
    }
....
}
```

To you actual question about search implementation. First [here](http://developer.qt.nokia.com/faq/answer/how_can_i_find_subitems_in_a_qtreewidget_using_finditems) is a nice snippet for implementation of the actual search functionality (not real-time). (sorry its c++ but i hope its fine).

To perform a real time search you have to connect a `void textChanged(const QString & text)` signal from `QLineEdit` to a slot where the search is performed.

I hope that answers your question

Comment: hey, thanks for your fast answer,
but sadly, no its not that what i searched for :)

i have connected the signal with a own function that handles the realtime search.

The problem isnt to find the items, the problem is to fill the tree with the "still shown items"

Comment: Than I would go about it this way. Once you have a list of shown items, you can delete the "hidden" items from the `QTreeWidget`. It seems to me there is no other way here, because the `QTreeWidget` takes ownership of `QTreeWidgetItem`s